# FindMaximum does not use requested WorkingPrecision

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization, arbitrary-precision

I think that there is a bug in the way FindMaximum handles WorkingPrecision for constrained problems.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem before? Is there a work around?

Here is an example in which the bug occurs:

```
fun[x_?NumberQ] := (Print["x = ", x, "  Precision = ", Precision[x]] ; 1 - x^4 ) ;

FindMaximum[ {fun[x],-1<=x<= 1} , {x,0.5`64} , AccuracyGoal->32 , PrecisionGoal->32 , WorkingPrecision -> 64 ]
```

I define a simple function fun that computes the function 1-x^4.
The function fun is only evaluated on numbers. (See below.)
It also prints x and its precision before returning the value.

Then, I use FindMaximum to find the maximum of fun in the interval -1<=x<=1. I request FindMaximum to do it with a working precision of 64.

However, all the evaluations of fun are done with machine precision,
which should not be the case. Here is the beginning of the output:

x = 0.5  Precision = MachinePrecision

x = 0.499994  Precision = MachinePrecision

x = 0.500006  Precision = MachinePrecision
...

If I do the same with an unconstrained problem, e.g.,

```
FindMaximum[ fun[x] , {x,-0.5`64} , AccuracyGoal -> 32 , PrecisionGoal -> 32 , WorkingPrecision->64 ]
```

Then things work correctly. The beginning of the output is:

x = -0.5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  Precision = 64.

x = -0.5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  Precision = 64.

x = -0.4999999999999999999999999999999899999999999999624920275479230684  Precision = 64.

This is a stripped down version of a more complicated problem I am
encountering. In the more complicated example fun[x] represents a
function that cannot be differentiated symbolically. Thus,
fun[x_?NumberQ] in the definition is used to prevent symbolic evaluation
and differentiation. I still want FindMaximum to use the specified precision.

I am using version:
12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I get the final answer the same in both cases even though the intermediate steps are different.

Comment: Same on `"12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)"`. Final answer is different for me (val at max): 0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999757106208010606 (without con) vs 0.999999999999999908088159333292595949421199205803065491294628413 (with con). `NMaximize` seems to work correctly with constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am not worried about the accuracy of the final answer in this case. In the real application fun is a much more complicated function, of more than one variable, and there I do worry about the precision. The issue is that FindMaximum does not seem to use the requested WorkingPrecision.
The problem does not occur with NMaximize, but using NMaximize would be hopeless for the real application.